# "Applications" and "places" instead of logos on panel on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-panel

How can I get "Applications" and "places" menus instead of logos (application icons) on my panel ?

What I would like :
I'd like something minimal like this,

[image: goal]

What I have :

[image: current situation]

Answer (score 0):

1) Install `gnome-shell-extensions` and `gnome-tweaks`

2) Open Gnome Tweaks and on the extensions tab
- Disable the extension "Ubuntu dock"
- Enable the extension "Applications menu" and "Places status indicator".

An extension to move the panel to the bottom unfortunately does not come with the software repositories. You need to resort to an extension from the [Gnome shell Extensions](https://extensions.gnome.org/#) website. [BottomPanel by abstract](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/949/bottompanel/) is good, and perhaps better, because better maintained, is [Frippery Bottom Panel by rmyorston](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/3/bottom-panel/).

To be able to install Gnome Shell extensions from the website, you need to install `chrome-gnome-shell`, and within your browser, you need to install the "Gnome Shell Integration" plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

1. In Dash-to-panel extension  : for hiding the applications icon, disable "Show *applications* icons" in the **behavior** tab.
2. Install the package "gnome-shell-extensions" : `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions` or install them from the gnome shell extension site ([Places Status Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/8/places-status-indicator/), [Applications Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6/applications-menu/))
3. In gnome-tweaks, enable the extensions : "**Applications menu**" and "**Places status indicator**"

[image: Applications menu with Dash-to-panel]
[image: Places menu with Dash-to-panel]

Add-on, if you want you can replace the text label by an icons for applications an places menu.

1. If you have installed the extensions with a package : copy the extensions files in you home directory :

   cp -R /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/ ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/

   cp -R /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/ ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
2. For Applications menu, `gedit ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/apps-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js`
   Replace this :

`this._label = new St.Label({`

`text: _('Applications'),`

`y_expand: true,`

`y_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER,`

`});`

By this :

```
this._label = new St.Icon({ icon_name: 'view-app-grid-symbolic', style_class: 'system-status-icon', icon_size: 32 });
```

3. For places menu, `gedit ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js`
   Replace this :

`let label = new St.Label({`

`text: _('Places'),`

`y_expand: true,`

`y_align: Clutter.ActorAlign.CENTER,`

`});`

By this :

```
let label = new St.Icon({ icon_name: 'folder-symbolic', style_class: 'system-status-icon', icon_size: 24 });
```

[image: Applications menu / icon as label with Dash-to-panel]
[image: Places indicator / icon as label with Dash-to-panel]

Comment: Or you use the Arc Menu Extension : https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1228/arc-menu/